# innerHTML doesn't function correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I am trying to populate a div using innerHTML, which works fantastically under all browsers except IE (specifically being tested under 8 and 9).  I can find lots of information on this topic, but no simple answers.  It seems to sometimes work if I don't have any tags in the text, but never with.  Can anyone help me understand the problem, and potential workarounds for this?

```
<html>
<body>

    The following box should contain text populated with innerHTML,
    but doesn't in IE
    <p id="inner" style="width:250px; height: 100px;  margin: 20px auto; background-color: #fff; border:5px solid orange; padding:7px; text-align:left; }"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txt = "<h1>Just a quick test!</h1>"  
        var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
        inner.innerHTML=txt;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know. its and unsupported thing in IE.

Comment: The error `Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Sun, 29 May 2011 16:28:57 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 11
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://eatyourpet.info/ietest/index.php`

Comment: No, it's not an "Unsupported thing". innerHTML is a feature that was first introduced by IE.

Comment: But this is the error that i am facing too... so could you please help?

Comment: You can't nest a H1 inside a P tag without triggering a runtime error. You can use a SPAN or other inline elements though.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the responses!  After making incremental changes from the many suggestions, the core problem turned out to be the last reply from EricLaw, where H1 was nested inside a P tag.  I wish IE would operate a little more like the major browsers, but it's good to know this problem was mine.  Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

It's erroring on `inner = document.getElementById("inner");` - if you change this to `var inner = document.getElementById("inner");` it will work.

IE is automatically creating a global `inner` variable due to the id on the element - it really doesn't seem to like you trying to assign things to it.

Comment: Ooop, I didn't notice that. I just placed the text inside an <h1> tag, which is actually the real issue, and the problem returns.  Are tags not supported in ie?

Answer (score 1):

Hit F12 to get the script debugger and review the script errors. For instance, rather than trying to assign what you hoped is a new variable named "inner" (which actually maps to the document's element with ID "inner") you might consider using a variable you've actually declared?

After you fix those, perhaps you want to delay your script until OnLoad fires?

Answer (score 1):

First your html is not complete. The page has no header (`<head>`).

Second, program precise, using comma's and semicolons everywhere you can. There was no punctuation after the variable declaration in your code. Things like that can break the script. In this case there is a conflict between `window[inner]` (an internal variable created by the browser) and your 'inner' variable. The lack of a comma/extra var declaration line confused the javascript interpreter, that tried to insert semicolons whilst interpreting. This 'semicolon insertion' is seen as one of the major flaws of javascript (see links @bottom), but can be circumvented with programmers discipline to always do his own semicolon insertion.

With a little more precision your script looks like:

```
var txt = "Just a quick test!", //use a comma here
           inner = document.getElementById("inner"); 
           //use a semicolon to end var declaration block
inner.innerHTML = txt; //always end statements with semicolon
```

or

```
var txt = "Just a quick test!";
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
```

That *will* work in IE.

[For further reading](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)
[For further reading (2)](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html)

Answer (score 0):

IE bombs out when trying to add HTML code into a P tag with innerHTML.
Replace your P tags with DIVs to solve the problem.